# How Name node update availability of Data Nodes for HDFS writes in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I have 10 Data nodes the replication factor is 3,file size is 150 and the block size is 64. So file will be splits into three blocks B1,B2,B3. So client  asks Name Node for the availability of Data nodes for writing B1 block. My question is how many Data nodes will be provided to client by Name node for writing B1 block.
And one more question is how the writes for B1,B2,B3 will be happend either parallelly or sequentially

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're encountering/trying to solve? This seems like you're just asking for background on how Hadoop works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Data will be written to just one datanode by client, rest replication is taken care by the datanodes itself on namenode instruction.
   `Replica placement`: while a datanode receives data of the block from the client, the datanode saves the data in a file, which represents the block, and, simultaneously re-sends the data to another datanode, which is supposed to create another replica of the block.
2. Blocks are copied sequentially

Comment: B1,B2,B3 blocks will be stored sequentially or parallelly?I mean first B1 isstored next B2 and then B3?

Comment: Sequentially as i have written in the answer above